# Python - Selenium - Get Parent Class

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, parent

I have a website http://demoqa.com/registration/

I have been trying to verify that when a user clicks on and then clicks off a required field such as username or phone number that the error "required field" appears when no data has been entered.

Does anyone have any idea how to verify this? I was thinking

```
phone = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Phone Number')]")
```

and then from that using something like getError = phone.find_element_by_xpath() and using the (..) to try and move up to the parent class, but with no luck!

I thought it would have been easy but all the elements have the same class name. I suppose I could check for the text "this field is required" but I'd like to keep it neat and write a method so I can use it on each of the fields.

I've spent alot of today searching for it and trying different thing, so any help or ideas would be great.

Thanks!

Other Info:

I can tell you what happens before and after i click the field. My best guess at attacking this issue would be to verify the class name of the field "phone number" and then once clicked off, verify that the class name has changed. As you can see on top is before a click off and below is when the required field text appears

```
<div class="fieldset">
    <label class="" for="phone_9">Phone Number</label>
    <input id="phone_9" class="input_fields piereg_validate[required,custom[phone_international]]" type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="phone_9">
</div>


<div class="fieldset error">
    <label class="" for="phone_9">Phone Number</label>
    <input id="phone_9" class="input_fields 
 piereg_validate[required,custom[phone_international]]" type="text" value="" 
 placeholder="" name="phone_9">
    <div class="legend_txt">
        <span class="legend error">* This field is required</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials please?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB  I really don't have much as I'm new to python, I normally write in C#. Here is the code I mentioned trying to work my way back up to the class temp = self.phone.find_element_by_xpath(".//ancestor::tr")

Answer (score 5):

I have my solution *i think

seeing how the "div class name" changes when the required message appears I have a solution. I first find the element, get it's parents name by going up one level using the (..), i verify it's as it should be named "fieldset". I think trigger the error message, and repeat the process but make sure the "fieldset" has changed to "fieldset error"

```
getElementBase = self.driver.find_element_by_id('phone_9')
getElementClassRoot = getElementBase.find_element_by_xpath('..')
getElementClassRootName = getElementClassRoot.get_attribute('class')
```

Comment: Good one. But note that you must be sure that application works correctly and if `"error"` class name appended to parent `div` it **really means that `span` with error message displayed**... Because if there is a bug - you might miss it... IMHO it's better to check the appearance of element in DOM and moreover make an assertion like `assert element.is_displayed()`

Comment: Good point! @Andersson I think I will implement both pieces of code into the test, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below piece of code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

error = "* This field is required"
phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[label='Phone Number']")
phone_input = phone.find_element_by_tag_name("input")
phone_label = phone.find_element_by_tag_name("label")
phone_input.click()
phone_label.click()
try:
    phone.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='legend error' and .='%s']" % error)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No error displayed")
```

This should allow you to click inside input, outside input and check that error appears

If you need to make an assertion:

```
result = True
try:
    phone.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='legend error' and .='%s']" % error)
except NoSuchElementException:
    result = False
assert result, "No error displayed"
```